# Use same fragment for infinite inner hierarchy

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a requirement to display infinite screen  using same fragment.For example If I have Category name "A" with subcategory "B" and "C" and sub category "B" contain other subcategory like "D" and "E" and so on.

So what I need to display category with infinite subcategory with Same fragment only.

I am trying using this by adding fragment one on other but when I go back the last updated list is appear on all back stack fragment.

Please suggest on this.

Thanks

Comment: Add some code in the question. Are you using Jetpack Navigation library? Where are you storing fragment specific data? In a ViewModel?

Comment: I am not using Jetpack components.I am using Simple Fragment .

Comment: Okay, but where are you saving your data? In fragment itself?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solutions using by transferring bundle data between fragment.
Basically mistake was for transferring data using RxBus.
RxBus update data to previous and next fragment.So I have replace it using Bundle.

```
var fragment:SubCategoryListFragment = SubCategoryListFragment()
                val bundle = Bundle()
                fragment.arguments=bundle
                bundle.putParcelable("data", categoryList.get(position))
                (mContext as AppBaseActivity).addFragmentToRoot(
                    fragment,
                    true,
                    true
                )
```

Thanks